# Await Task.Run wait until finished then do an action

Tags: c#, async-await

Here is the code, question is how can I track when this is finished and then run something else? Trying to copy the completed zip to a storage location

```
private async void ZipFolder(string src, string dest, bool delete)  
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var zipFile = new ZipFile())
        {
            // add content to zip here 
            zipFile.AddDirectory(src);
            zipFile.SaveProgress +=
                (o, args) =>
                {
                    var percentage = (int)(1.0d / args.TotalBytesToTransfer * args.BytesTransferred * 100.0d);
                    // report your progress
                    pbCurrentFile.Dispatcher.Invoke(
                        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(
                        delegate()
                        {
                            lblCurrentFile.Content = "Compressing " + src;
                            pbCurrentFile.Value = percentage;
                        }
                        ));
                };
            zipFile.Save(dest);

            if(delete)
            {
                Directory.Delete(src, true);
            }

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but if you add more code after `await Task.Run` it will be executed only after the task is completed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method should return a `Task`, not `void`.  You can then `await` that task to run an operation when it finishes, or use `ContinueWith` if you want to add a continuation the old fashioned way.

There's also no *real* need for this method to be `async`.  You can just `return` the result of `Task.Run` instead of awaiting it, since this method isn't doing anything after that call finishes.

Additionally, a more idiomatic method of reporting progress would be for this method to accept an `IProgress<int>` in which the caller indicates how to update the UI with progress, rather than  mixing the UI code with the business logic.

Comment: @ondrovic I'm confident in your ability to make the changes that I have described to your code.  The changes are generally short and simple, and you can find more information on any of these topics through additional research if you are struggling.  If I simply give you code that you can copy-paste you won't be able to effectively learn how to apply these concepts to your code.